# Override default ActionMailer recipient at controller level

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

For demonstration purposes, I would like to override the Rails 4 ActionMailer recipient at controller level.

The following initializer does what I want, but when I want to change `mail.to` address, I need to recommit my code and restart the server.

```
# config/initializers/override_mail_recipient.rb
if Rails.env.production?
  class OverrideMailRecipient
    def self.delivering_email(mail)
      mail.to = 'example@domain.com'
    end
  end
  ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(OverrideMailRecipient)
end
```

What I would want is to be able to access a link like:

```
get '/default_mail_recipient/:email' => 'controller#default_mail_recipient', as: :mail_recipient
```

And then in a controller:

```
def default_mail_recipient
    ActionMailer::Base.override_recipient = params[:email]
    redirect_to :root, :notice => "Default mail recipient overridden"
end
```

I doubt that this will be possible, but maybe there's a Rails ninja out there that might help me or point me in another direction.

Comment: Do you want to override the recipient forever? or just for one email? or how should that work?

Comment: The idea is that there are three or four people doing presentation of a development environment of a website to clients, and then have the ability to override all mails temporarily while doing the presentation (for all user confirmation and invitation mails). These guys don't have developer access and there may be more than one presentation scheduled on a specified date, so they might want to change it on demand. I hope this is a bit clearer.